# Controlling SQL Backups From Two Machines

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

I'm far from a DBA, and don't really have a great understanding of backup chains, but I was asked the following question by a network administrator, and wanted to be sure that my answer was correct.

We have Symantec Backup Exec 2012, which currently takes care of full backups for databases either every day or every week, depending on the usage of that database.

As well as the fulls, BE is also doing incremental backups of the transaction logs either every 30 mins or every 2 hours, again depending on the usage of that database.

Our BE server is also responsible for other storage, cluster and virtual machine backups, and only has so many slots available to run jobs simultaneously.

I have been asked if it is possible for BE to be responsible for the full backups, but have SQL natively handle log file backups (with BE probably then backing up the actual .bak file every couple of hours).

I know that if I try to do an incremental backup in BE, and the last backup was not done by BE, it will fail because the LSN is off (rather, I think this is the reason). However I am not sure how the chain is impacted if all the transaction log backups are done in one device, and the full is done in another. Do transaction log backups work from the last log backup and then also from the last full backup if that occurred later?

If this question needs any clarification (because I've used terms incorrectly, for example) then please just let me know and I will modify as appropriate.

Thanks in advance for your time and advice.

Comment: Full backups do not affect transaction log chain in any way. You can take full backup using BE and then can take SQL Server transaction Log backup using native TSQL. I hope this is what you are asking ?

Comment: Yes, more or less. I just wanted to be sure of the following scenario:
a transaction log backup was taken at 12:30, 
a full backup completed at 12:45, 
a transaction log was taken at 1:00

I would not have any issues with a full occurring from a different source since the last transaction log backup took place. If I wanted to recover to the 1:00 backup, I would just have to apply that to the last full taken in BE?

Comment: @AdamH Correct.

Comment: No it would not affect. Just make sure no body else tries to take full backup using TSQL. If they really want to take backup they can use COPY_ONLY clause in TSQL backup script this would not affect BE backups

Comment: Flag as dupe, essentially the same question, with some good answers that address the concern.